# ipv6calc outputs wrong address when converting from ipv4 to ipv6?

Tags: bash, ipv6

Having a strange issue while trying to convert an ipv4 list file to ipv6:

```
ipv6calc -q --action conv6to4 --in ipv4 1.1.23.1 --out ipv6
2002:101:1701::
```

Trying to validate that result is correct, I used some online converters and it seems that 1.1.23.1 is 2002:0:0:0:0:0:101:1701 (or else 2002::101:1701).
So the last "::" should be removed & 2002 should have extra ":".

I really don't want to use sed/awk commands in order to manipulate this result, so the questions are:

1. is there alternative cmd/linux SW?
2. is this somehow fixed inside ipv6 calc, am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You do realize you are not actually converting IPv4 addresses to IPv6, don't you? What this is supposed to do is create an IPv6 address for a 6to4 relay service.

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct 6to4 address. A 6to4 subnet is on the format `2002:IP4_HI:IP4_LO::/48`. `IP4_HI` is the top 16 bits of the IPv4 address, while `IP4_LO` is the low 16 bits of the address.

For example, the IPv4 address `1.2.3.4` gives you the 6to4 subnet `2002:0102:0304::/48`.

See [6to4 address block allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6to4#Address_block_allocation) for more details.

A different question is whether this is actually the address you want? There are other ways to map IPv4 addresses to IPv6 addresses. For example, there are [IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv4-mapped_IPv6_addresses), which are typically written as `::ffff:1.2.3.4`.

The address format you need depends on what you are going to use it for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, also read your link. However, when i try this format, my server denies as 'invalid ipv6 address'. In subnetonline i can see that 1.2.3.4 is translated to 2002::102:304, so i still don't get it.

Comment: You haven't said anything about what you are going to use the address for, so all we can do is guess. Note that what I wrote were 6to4 subnets, and not single addresses. Each IPv4 address gets a subnet of 2^80 different IPv6 addresses using 6to4.

Comment: Yup, i didn't..it's about network element config..I needed 1.1.21.1/24 to convert to ipv6 format (/120 i guess, according to same hosts). Machine only takes 2002:: format, any other seems to be invalid (as your example above). So i've got online converters showing my initial, 'correct' format, while ipv6 provides different output.

Comment: @aprin, I hope you don't intend to use such contrived addresses on the Internet. There really is no magic IPv4-to-IPv6 address conversion. Also, using /120 subnets will get you into trouble with IPv6 since using subnets with masks longer than /64 (except for a few special circumstances) will cause problems.

Comment: @RonMaupin: Depending on the purpose, a /120 makes perfect sense in a configuration. For example, if I rewrite a a previously IPv4-only server to accept both IPv6 and IPv4 connections (using the `IPV6_V6ONLY` option), that socket will start receiving IPv4 connections using IPv4 mapped IPv6 addresses, which means that I would have to transform access control lists in the application from for example `1.2.3.0/24` into `::ffff:1.2.3.0/120`.

Comment: @aprin: I still don't see exactly what you are doing with the addresses/subnets, but my previous comment here illustrates one example, where one would use a standard IPv4-mapped IPv6 address. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: I am only trying to test a scenario by using ipv6 addresses, while i already have the ipv4 scenario. I need to convert ipv4 existing addresses (/24) to ipv6 (/120), and run this scenario. No mixed ipv6-ipv4 formats allowed. I need to find a script which follows "online converter rules" and get the list in ipv6 format.

Comment: @olav, you misunderstand. The IPv4-mapped addresses are an exception. I was referring to the OP's address range. I looked the the subnetonline.com site, and it has enough wrong to be dangerous. For instance, the site claims to be able to translate IPv4 broadcast addresses to IPv6 multicast. It also doesn't seem to understand that you can use the first and last addresses in an IPv6 subnet.

Comment: I still haven't figured out what OP's intentions actually are, so I am obviously reading different things into it than you are :) Since the only case where I have had to deal with this kind of address conversions are for access control lists, I naturally think in those terms. Now I am starting to fear that the goal is to configure a network adapter, which (as you are saying), doesn't make sense.

Comment: @aprin: I am still unable to understand what you are trying to do with the addresses you convert from IPv4 to IPv6. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Check ipv6 functionality. This is dummy configuration. Just need to apply ipv6 addresses instead of ipv4. Got ipv4 list ready, want to convert to ipv6.